# multiple datatype in a armadillo matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

I want to create a matrix in Armadillo, which can keep different datatypes in a matrix. For example, I want to have a matrix with three integer columns, a float column, and a column with enumeration value. Is there any solution?

Comment: Looks like you don't want to use this for mathematical calculations? Cause it sounds like you want to abuse a matrix to represent some other datastructure. Maybe a vector of objects wil lod the same.

Comment: @churill I just ask about the possibilities in Armadillo. As you know, Matlab can keep complex matrix with the different datatypes. In other words, Matlab doesn't care about datatype and keep anything you want in a cell of the matrix.

Comment: @Alireza_Armn But you have to think of the reason, why you want to this. Do you want to use it for some calculation? You can easily convert ints and enum values to floats. Or do you want to represent some datastructure, where each line represents an entity? Then a vector would probably be better. I don't know how Armadillo works, I just want to help you to avoid design decisison that might get ugly, because it sounds like an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @churill Thanks for your help. Let me explain the X problem ;) I want to keep some matrixes with different dimensions in a matrix. My mission is that convert Matlab codes to c++ codes in a way that the structure of codes stays the same as the original Matlab codes.

Comment: @Alireza_Armn In C++ it's better to organize informationin classes, than to store then as raw values in some matrix.

Comment: @Alireza_Armn Have you considered the [field class](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#field) in Armadillo?  Each element in a field can be a matrix, cube, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Armadillo matrices store all elements internally as a standard C array of the element datatype. That means all elements must have the same type. This makes sense for armadillo since it is intended to be used for linear algebra and numerical computations, and not as a general container.

For your particular case it is probably better to simply create separated objects. You could, for instance, create a matrix of integers (arma::imat or arma::umat depending if you want sign), a vector of floats (arma::vec) and for the column of enumeration you could use std::vector.

Then you can create a struct with three fields to store these objects (or use a tuple) if you always want to keep them together (to easily pass them as arguments, for instance).